# Error opening a Salesforce File after creating a content version using REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, http, base64, salesforce

I am using typescript (angular 4) to post to the salesforce endpoint 
`https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/` 
My http request looks like the following

```html
Request Headers
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="1524931327799"
Authorization: Bearer <token>


Request Body
--1524931327799
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_document";
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{  
  "PathOnClient" : "IMG_0400.jpg",
  "Title": "IMG_0400.jpg"
}

--1524931327799
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="IMG_0400.jpg"

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QBsRXhpZgAASUkqAAgA <rest of base64 data>

--1524931327799--
```

After opening the image on the salesforce platform I get an error that the image may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize. When I open the image using text edit there is the identical base64 data that is sent in the request. It seems the problem comes with salesforce not recognizing that the file is an image and does not decode the base64 data. All and any help is welcomed! Thank you.

Comment: You should send the raw binary data not base64 encoded.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse! Unfortunately, I have tried just sending the raw binary and it results in the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it using developer workbench and request like this should work just fine. Try not to define 2 different content types in the request, rather put definition of file into the VersionData attribute of ContentVersion Object

```
{  
  "PathOnClient" : "IMG_0400.jpg",
  "Title": "IMG_0400.jpg",
  "VersionData" : "4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QBsRXhpZgAASUkqAAgA"
}
```

Comment: Did you use the same content type for the ContentVersion Object and the VersionData? When I use the same or remove one, I get a 400 Bad Request error. Also, after adding the versiondata in the object I still resulting in the same error after trying to open the file on SF's side

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to post to the /ContentVersion/ endpoint. After doing some research the simplest solution I found was to use jsforce https://jsforce.github.io/.

Solution using jsforce:
1. Import jsforce library in your index.html "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsforce/1.7.0/jsforce.min.js"
2. Import jsforce at the top of your angular component

```js
declare var jsforce:any;
```

3. Start a connection with jsforce

```js
        var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
          loginUrl: "https://test.salesforce.com/",
          clientId : "",
          clientSecret : "",
          redirectUri : ""
        });
```

3. Login to SF and post to composite endpoint using requestPost

```js
var username = "";
var password = "";
conn.login(username, password, function(err, userInfo) {
          if (err) { return console.error(err); }
          var path = '/services/data/v41.0';
          return conn.requestPost( path + '/composite/', {
              'allOrNone' : true,
              'compositeRequest' : [
                  {
                      'method' : 'POST',
                      'url' : path + '/sobjects/ContentVersion/',
                      'referenceId' : 'newFile',
                      'body' : {
                          'Title' : fileToPost.name,
                          'PathOnClient' : fileToPost.name,
                          'VersionData' : base64FileData
                      }
                  }
              ]
          })
```